# milkcocoa APIにスマホアプリからアクセスする場合のセキュリティ

Tags: android, javascript, ios, milkcocoa

[milkcocoa](https://mlkcca.com)をiOSやAndroidなどのスマホアプリから利用する場合はアクセス制御などはどういう風にするべきななんでしょうか?

Comment: 具体的に問題に感じている・やりたいことは何でしょうか。ドキュメントに[セキュリティルール](https://mlkcca.com/document/security.html)というページがありますが、ここに書かれているアクセス制御以上のことをしたいということでしょうか。 (既に解決しているのに気付かずコメントしましたが残しておきます)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

開発者の落合です。

生成したアプリの情報を通信に持たせてサーバー側で認証するアプリ側の同一生成元ポリシーのようなものを具体例の一つとして、現在仕様を策定中になります。

現在のブラウザ用Origin設定のようなインターフェース、あるいはより簡単な方法で実現できないかと模索しています。

現状のiOSテスト版だと、セキュリティルールを用いてホワイトリスト的に使用可能なDataStore/API/Userを限定し、アプリの中身を調査したユーザーがappidを知っても問題のないような作りにするのが無難かと思われます。